# Convert DOMXpath to an HTML string

Tags: html, xpath, domxpath

Is there way to convert the DOMXpath object back to HTML? I would like to replace one section of the HTML

```
<div class='original'>Stuff</div>
```

replaced with:

```
<div class='replacement'>New Stuff</div>
```

and then return it back to a valid Xpath. I know that the function DOMDocument::saveHTML exists, but if I do

```
 XPATH->saveHTML();
```

I get an error. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) always works on a `DOMDocument` instance, so you should always save the `DOMDocument` instead. See a working demo example below :

```
<?php
  $xml = "<parent><div class='original'>Stuff</div></parent>";
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadXML($xml);
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

  //get element to be replaced
  $old = $xpath->query("/parent/div")->item(0);

  //create new element for replacement
  $new = $doc->createElement("div");
  $new->setAttribute("class", "replacement");
  $new->nodeValue = "New Stuff";

  //replace old element with the new one
  $old->parentNode->replaceChild($new, $old);

  //TODO: save the modified HTML instead of echo
  echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/529177)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<parent><div class="replacement">New Stuff</div></parent>
```